# Save a WebPage on Android

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to configure my app to store a webpage. if the mobile has access to internet to show it later when it has no access.

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can save Web view Archive by **(Added in API 11)**

```
 webView.saveWebArchive(String filename)
```

Comment: i cant open the link on my computer. and can you tell me the method samplely?

Comment: It saves as a xml file. And i can't get it out normally. How can i get it out with webview?